# read csv file exportc-csv to multiple files

Tags: powershell, csv

I've created an csv file with a couple or rows. Think now is to import that file and create a new file per row. So every row get its own file with content.

I've created the following powershell code:

```
$Import = import-csv C:\temp\output.csv

$CreateFileName = $Import | Select-Object $_.TicketNumber -Expand "TicketNumber"
foreach ($row in $Import)
  {
    export-csv -Path $row.CreateFileName.csv -noType
  }
```

When running this script i've got the following error:

```
cmdlet Export-Csv at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
InputObject:
```

Comment: `Export-Csv` won't work with the expanded values as you seem to expect. What is your desired result? Do you want one file per ticket number with just the ticket number as the content of the file?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the output file to contain the ticket number with the header line `TicketNumber` you could do something like this:

```
Import-Csv 'C:\temp\output.csv' | select TicketNumber | % {
  Export-Csv -Input $_ -Path "$($_.TicketNumber).CreateFileName.csv" -noType
}
```

If you want the output file to contain just the ticket number (without header line) you could do something like this instead:

```
Import-Csv 'C:\temp\output.csv' | select TicketNumber -Expand TicketNumber | % {
  Set-Content "$_.CreateFileName.csv" $_
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because the following is not returning anything:

```
$row.CreateFileName.csv
```

So the whole line becomes:

```
export-csv -Path -noType
```

and PowerShell helpfully thinks you are forgetting the path.